# Magento2 REST API. Attribute to attribute group

Tags: rest, api, attributes, magento2

Is there any way to assign attribute to attribute group through REST API(http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index_20.html)?

I can assign attribute group to attribute set, but did not find way assign attribute to attribute group. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old, but i thought I'd share my answer for fellow googler's. I stumbled across this question when searching for a way to check if an attribute has already been assigned to a group. If anybody has an answer I'd love to hear it!

The Endpoint, **CatalogProductAttributeManagementV1 (https://*yourmagentohost*.com/rest/{all|default}/V1/products/attribute-sets/attributes)**, is described in [Magento 2 Swagger Doc](http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/) as having a **POST**'ing method that will assign an attribute to an attribute set.

However, it fails to mention that it also assigns the attribute to a group at the same time using the **attributeGroupId** property:

**Implementation Notes**

Assign attribute to attribute set

**Body (Content in POST)**

```
{
    "attributeSetId": 0,
    "attributeGroupId": 0,
    "attributeCode": "string",
    "sortOrder": 0
}
```

**Response**

```
"integer as string?"
```